# Translate xml string to html, I received error messages

Tags: python, xml, django

Hi I received error messages with this.

this is the error message

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

this is my code

```
self.task_xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <django-objects version="1.0">
<object model="task.task" pk="31">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="32">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="33">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="34">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
</django-objects>"

    self.xmlData = ET.fromstring(self.task_xml)

    self.xmlList = []
    for obj in self.xmlData.iter("object"):
        self.xmlList.append({'id': obj.find("object[@name='pk']").text,
                    'name': obj.find("field[@name='name']").text,
                    'parent_task_id': obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text,
                    }
```

I just wanted to copy the id from:

```
<object model="task.task" pk="33">
```

and I am sure this isn't correct.

```
'id': obj.find("object[@name='pk']").text
```

can you please help me know the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is either `lxml.etree` or `xml.etree.ElementTree`, you are doing it wrongly, you are trying to find a node with the `object` node with tag `object` and that has `name` attribute as `pk` , which is not correct.

You want to do the following -

```
self.xmlList = []
for obj in self.xmlData.iter("object"):
    self.xmlList.append({'id': obj.get('pk'),
                'name': obj.find("field[@name='name']").text,
                'parent_task_id': obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text,
                }
```

`obj.get('pk')` gets the value of the `pk` attribute from the object node.