# How to filter xml string like i do in database

Tags: python, xml, django, string, filter

I want only to show data where parent_task_id == 0

```
self.task_xml = """
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<django-objects version="1.0">
    <object model="task.task" pk="31">
        <field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
        <field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
    </object>
    <object model="task.task" pk="32">
        <field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
        <field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
    </object>
    <object model="task.task" pk="33">
        <field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
        <field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
    </object>
    <object model="task.task" pk="34">
        <field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
        <field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
    </object>
</django-objects>
"""

self.xmlData = ET.fromstring(self.task_xml)

self.xmlList = []
for obj in self.xmlData.iter("object"):
    self.xmlList.append({'id': obj.find("object[@name='pk']").text,
                'name': obj.find("field[@name='name']").text,
                'parent_task_id': obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text,
                }
```

I want to do something that I do with models if i use the database

```
Task.objects.filter(parent_task_id=0)
```

but this time i am using xml string, it there any function to do this ?

Comment: What do you mean `show data where parent_task_id == 0` , do you mean you only want to store elements in `self.xmlList` where that condition is met?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I only want to show elements where parents_task_id is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again, your method of getting the `id` is wrong, you need to get the attribute `pk` from the `object` node, not - `obj.find("object[@name='pk']").text` - As already answered in - [Translate xml string to html, I received error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109444/translate-xml-string-to-html-i-received-error-messages) .

Then for the current required just get the information - `obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text` , and check if it is equal to `0` and only if it is equal to `0` , append the data to the xmlList.

Example -

```
self.xmlList = []
for obj in self.xmlData.iter("object"):
    parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
    if parent_task_id == '0':
        self.xmlList.append({'id': obj.get('pk'),
                'name': obj.find("field[@name='name']").text,
                'parent_task_id': ,
                }
```

Comment: Ah, yeah right. I wasn't able to change it when i created a new question. Thank you so much for answering my question. I really hope to be better at python.

Comment: I will. I just did. Thanks again